# How can you toughen up your foot for barefoot kicking?

Tags: american-football, training

I'm a mom of a 13-year-old boy.
He loves football. (Me, not so much. No dad.) So after football season was over, he and his buddies were at school playing football, and my son was kicking the ball. Then for what ever reason he decided to take his shoe off and kick the ball. His coach saw him and worked with him, and said he was twice as accurate without his shoe and got more height and distance. Coach said he was on the team when school starts back up based on what he had seen. I think they call it American Wedge kicking.

But he needs to toughen up his foot. He practices everyday. How does he toughen his foot up?

Of course we are from Texas, and football rules.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How does he toughen up his foot

Comment: Yes that is my question. He needs to toughen his foot up.

Comment: Is this meant to be an [tag:american-football] question?

Comment: @PhilipKendall Given all of the information, I think it clearly is.

Answer (score 1):

Practice makes perfect. The more he kicks barefoot the tougher his foot will become over time. Look at thai/kick-boxers, they practically toughen up their shins by kicking over and over again. I should warn however, it's likely that his foot will get sore, he might get bruises on his foot if he's practising a lot..

But leaving the question aside, does it really matter for him to train kicking barefoot? I mean, he will most likely not take off his shoes before taking a kick during a game, so why practice something that you will not be able to do, instead of training to shoot better *with* his shoes?

Comment: No he will be kicking barefoot in the games are state allows it in school

Comment: @luann could you ask the coach this question?  I would also check with your pediatrician to see if there are any safety concerns you should be aware of.

Answer (score 0):

Continue kicking and it will toughen up.

Have you considered looking into a shoe made for kicking? It may be that the shoe he was kicking with was inferior for kicking. Basketball shoes or any type of high-top would be a bad idea unless it is has a [square toe and you're going for a traditional style.](http://www.squaretoekickingshoes.com/)

Some have a cover over the laces:  http://wizardkicking.com/kicking-shoes.html